# How to start creating a package to read a signal and publish it in a ROS network

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, publisher, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to ROS and programing and I  would like some advices to develop a ROS package/node that reads a radio signal, so far I can only access it from its IPs address from a browser like a internet wifi modem,  and pusblish it so I could use it in a ROS network.

Any Advices, papers, links, to start this journey ???

Thanks a lot in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325675/how-to-start-creating-a-package-to-read-a-signal-and-publish-it-in-a-ros-network/) by [Paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29563/paulo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2019-06-13**:
I think further clarification is needed here. What "radio signal" are you talking about? Radar? Are you asking about how to write a node that communicates with some sensor and publishes the data in ROS?

**Comment by [Paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29563/paulo/) on 2019-06-13**:
Hi. It's basically a rocket m900, one access point and one client connect via wifi. I would like to monitor it and send the signal strength through a ROS network. Although I'm not familiar with getting the signal data, that is not in any ROS package, and publish it in my ROS network. I can initially access it like a common wifi router and see some statistics. I would like some tips and material to start developing a way to publish this that in my ROS network. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your first task will be to write a c++ or python program that can access the signal strength information you need. If you can monitor it over HTTP can you send a [CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) request and receive a text response that contains the signal strength? Your program will then need to parse this text and extract the raw strength reading.

When you have this working you can adapt the [simple publisher example](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) to publish the data to a topic.

Hope this gives you enough to get started.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29563/paulo/) on 2019-06-13**:
Nice . I'll check that as well. Thank you

**Comment by [Paulo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29563/paulo/) on 2019-06-18**:
Hello, it helped me indeed. Thanks. I am able to get my data through a PHP script now.

Is it possible to use it with ROS in a python package?

Thank you a lot

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-18**:
Yes it is certainly possible. I recommend us using one of the python CURL libraries such as [pycURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html) That way you will be able to get the data in the same way from a python ROS node. Then is should be fairly straight forward to publish the data over a topic.